# Variance of stochastic process

Tags: time-series, variance

I have a short question. I have a process x(t)=p*x(t-1)+v(t), where v(t) is N(0,s^2) and lpl < 1. Now I want to know what the Var(x(t)-x(t-1)) is.

I know Var(x(t)-x(t-1)) = Var(x(t)) + Var(x(t-1)) - 2Cov (x(t), x(t-1)).
Now the variances should be the same if I'm correct?! But what about the covariance?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably better suited to be posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

From a programming point of view I would think of your question as a simulation experiment.

In the R sofware, you can generate data from the autoregressive process and compute the sample variance of the differences in the simulated data. To refine it, you can do it several times, say, 1000 and take the average value. For example, with rho=0.6 and s=4:

```
set.seed(123)
rho <- 0.6
s <- 4
vals <- NULL
for (i in seq(1000))
{
  x <- arima.sim(model = list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = rho), n = 500, sd = s)
  vals <- c(vals, var(diff(x)))
}
mean(vals)
#[1] 20.10488
```

Analytically, you may rewrite your equation subtracting x(t-1) in both sides of the equation:

x(t) - x(t-1) = rho * x(t-1) - x(t-1) + v(t)

Then, obtain the expression for the variance of x(t-1) (the same as for x(t)) and use it to obtain the variance in the above expression. If I am correct, you should arrive to:

Var(x(t) - x(t-1)) = (rho - 1)^2 * (s^2/(1 - rho^2) + s^2

```
(rho - 1)^2 * (s^2 / (1 - rho^2)) + s^2
#[1] 20 # to be compared with 'mean(vals)' above
```